# What is the retain/release policy for NSDecimalNumberHandler

Tags: iphone, release, retain

If a NSDecimalNumberHandler is created using the following:

```
(id)decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:(NSRoundingMode)roundingMode scale:(short)scale raiseOnExactness:(BOOL)raiseOnExactness raiseOnOverflow:(BOOL)raiseOnOverflow raiseOnUnderflow:(BOOL)raiseOnUnderflow raiseOnDivideByZero:(BOOL)raiseOnDivideByZero
```

1) Then is it already retained when it is returned? Or is it autoreleased?

2) And subsequently, should we be responsible for "release"-ing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Then is it already retained when it is returned? Or is it autoreleased?**

*It returns an autoreleased object, since the method does not contain new alloc or init on its name, therefore you should `retain` it.*

**2) And subsequently, should we be responsible for "release"-ing it?**

*Since you send it a retain message and you "own" it, therefore you are responsible for sending the `release` message.*